# Conway "A Course In Functional Analysis" Proposition 4.14, the cardinality argument

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I am a bit confused on the following argument, the part that is highlighted:
[image]

What does it mean that $\epsilon \cdot \aleph_0 = \epsilon$, does that mean that there exist a
bijection between an infinite set and a countable copy of it? Can anyone give a proof?

Comment: This is a standard fact about [cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_multiplication): the product $\alpha \cdot \beta$ of two infinite cardinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is equal to the larger of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: It means if $S$ is infinite and $T$ is countably infinite, then $S\times T$ has the same cardinality as $S.$

Comment: @MkSn1999 Note that this is obvious for any cardinality that can be written as $\varepsilon \cdot \aleph_0$, since we already know that $\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$.  So it shouldn't be that surprising.

Comment: Thanks, can someone refer me to a proof?

Comment: I've tried to find an online proof, but everything I found either stated the result without proof, or was garbage. The first steps are easy. Assume $0 \ne \alpha \le \beta$. Then it is simple to show that $\beta \le \alpha \cdot \beta \le \beta \cdot \beta$. So it remains to show that $\beta^2 = \beta$. For that, let $\mu$ be the smallest *ordinal* with $|\mu| = \beta$. Use the well-ordering of $\mu$ to create a bijection between $\mu$ and $\mu \times \mu$ similar to the proof that $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N$ are bijective. (Note that this result requires the axiom of choice.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for the proof. To understand the part $\beta^2 = \beta$, do I have to use ordinals or is there a way to work around it? I am not quite familiar with the concept, could you suggest some readings? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, if I had a resource available I could had directed you to, I would have done so. That was why I was looking on-line. Failing that, I tried to recall as much as I could about how to prove it, and reproduced that. Unfortunately the rest I do not recall (if I ever even fully learned it). This was as far as I could go. Which is also why it is a comment, not an answer. I only gave the easy part. The hard part is what is left.